# Modifying Microsoft Outlook contacts from Python

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, mapi

I have written a few Python tools in the past to extract data from my Outlook contacts. Now, I am trying to *modify* my Outlook Contacts. I am finding that my changes are being noted by Outlook, but they aren't sticking. I seem to be updating some cache, but not the real record.

The code is straightforward.

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
profile = ns.Folders.Item("My Profile Name")
contacts = profile.Folders.Item("Contacts")
contact = contacts.Items[43] # Grab a random contact, for this example.
print "About to overwrite ",contact.FirstName, contact.LastName
contact.categories = 'Supplier' # Override the categories

# Edit: I don't always do these last steps.
ns = None 
o = None
```

At this point, I change over to Outlook, which is opened to the Detailed Address Cards view.

I look at the contact summary (without opening it) and the category is unchanged (not refreshed?).

I open the contact and its category HAS changed, *sometimes*. (Not sure of when, but it feels like it is cache related.) If it has changed, it prompts me to Save Changes when I close it which is odd, because I haven't changed anything in the Outlook UI.

If I quit and restart Outlook, the changes are gone.

I *suspect* I am failing to call [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842181.aspx), but I can't see which object supports it.

So my question is:

- Should I be calling SaveChanges? If so, where is it?
- Am I making some other silly mistake, which is causing my data to be discarded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is a .Save() method on the contact, so you need to add:

contact.Save()

Comment: this helped me to. I was doing 
contact.Save
because I'd been reading the microsoft reference. Without the () there's no error message, but of course it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately calling Save() takes about a second for single item on IMAP acount for me, and I need to modify many items. Any ideas?