# Working with Outlook Redemption in Python

Tags: python, outlook-redemption

Okay, so here is my current problem which can be broken down into several parts, and any advice on any part would be greatly appreciated!

1. Overview of general problem: I have several PST files in which every email contained within the PST files has a tag that I need to remove. The end goal is a PST file minus the tag (the tag is 3 lines of text in each email bracketed on the top and bottom by lines of *).
2. To solve this, I wanted to be able to manipulate the PSTs in Python.
3. In order to manipulate in Python, I found out that i could use [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) and its MAPI tables (I have not used any MAPI tables before).
4. Outlook Redemption is deployed in a DLL file, and I have never had to import a DLL file into Python before, so I checked Stack Overflow and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python). However, I don't understand these lines:

   ```
   # Actually map the call ("HLLAPI(...)") to a Python name. 
   hllApi = hllApiProto (("HLLAPI", hllDll), hllApiParams)
   ```

   What should I put in the space denoted by "...", and does he mean anything special by mapping it to a Python name?

Like I said, any help / advice / suggestions / pity would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Python, but it looks like you can use Redemption just like any other COM object:
[Modifying Microsoft Outlook contacts from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405724/modifying-microsoft-outlook-contacts-from-python)

```
import win32com.client 
import pywintypes 

session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession") 
...
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is make sure you include the line `win32.com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")` because sometimes if you do not have that you could end up not finding everything you need.