# Accessing MS-Outlook Mails (MAPI) from Rapidminer

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-2007, rapidminer

Rapidminer is a nice tool to process data.
Unfortunately it does not have an access node to MS-Outlook (2007) Emails. (Unless somebody can diret me to the opposite.

Therefore my question, has someone a solution available by using a Python- or R-script.

There are several snippets on how to access the MAPI from Python, but I am not clear on how to pass them as documents to Rapidminer.

Links MAPI from Python:

[Reading e-mails from Outlook with Python through MAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077625/reading-e-mails-from-outlook-with-python-through-mapi)

[Modifying Microsoft Outlook contacts from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405724/modifying-microsoft-outlook-contacts-from-python)

Comment: If you are using Outlook in a corporate environment then you should know that MS Exchange comes with programmatic access to the message store disabled by default. And I have never come across an Exchange administrator who was prepared to change that default.

Comment: I am asking for outlook (2007) specifically.

Comment: And Outlook 2007 doesn't use Exchange? You can use MAPI to talk to very old versions of Outlook Express.

Comment: @BoarGules - "disabled by default"? What API is disabled by default? Use MAPI to talk to Outlook Express? You are mixing Extended MAPiI and Simple MAPI. They have nothing in common.

Comment: @BoarGules There is no Exchange anywhere! I am talking about a local (desktop) installation, where I have mails which I'd like to process. And MAPI is one interface I know to acess mails (and other elements) from Outlook. I have done this already with VBA as a macro. But here I am looking to get Emails to Rapidminer.

Comment: I began my comment with *If you are using Outlook in a corporate environment.* You're clearly not, so the comment doesn't apply. I believe you could have just ignored it.

Comment: Appologies if this was to direct. I wrote _twice MS-Outlook (2007)_

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice [Python RapidMiner Extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_python_scripting) tool that you can download free from the RapidMiner marketplace.  If you re-post in the [RapidMiner user community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com/), others may chime in.